# How to show notifications even if the user is not using the website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, web

How do some websites show notifications even if the user is not accessing the website?
For example, consider Facebook messenger. Even though the page is not open, you will get a notification. Or consider twitter. I am not a big user of twitter but I know that it also shows such notifications.


I am going to use Angular Framework for frontend and Express-Node.js Framework for backend.
Also can this be implemented in Android devices and iPhones?
What is the browser compatibility?

**PS:** I have a lot of questions because I have absolutely no idea how they are implemented. So please bear with me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Push notifications. Use a backend such as firebase to implement it easily.

Comment: [serviceworke.rs](https://serviceworke.rs/) (by Mozilla) has some great examples on how to do this.

Comment: just a clarification: If you use an App, like messenger is, It's not a webpage that sends a notification, it's the application itself. An application can contact the web, like facebook's server, to get data. Nothing to do with having a browser open or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about service workers and push notifications.

Service workers can be used for listening to updates from a specific app's server and reacting to them. 
You can provoke a notification once a message was sent. Google, Amazon and other cloud services provide this kind of service. Also, you can implement one by yourself. I recommend Google for a quick win :).

Here's a great tutorial by Google: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications

Enjoy.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -3):

They use webpush notifications. The flow:

- a Site registers a [serviceworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)
- Service worker subscribes to [push](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications) notifications. You can check the flow [here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-integrating-web-push).
- Your browser listens to Push server. When push server notifies browser, the browser wakes up (or starts) your service worker that handles that notification.